# Public Static objects are being disposed

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have the following class which I use to store `SQLite` reader data to draw into a paintevent to draw on a winform when `Invalidate()` is called.
The class has been created as follows:

```
public class Reader
{
    static public SQLiteDataReader nodes;
    static public SQLiteDataReader conduits;
    static public SQLiteDataReader catchments;
}
```

and as an example a variable of that class is assigned as follows:

```
 //click event when a conduit is created
 SQLiteDataReader reader = SqlConnections.FindNode(x, y); //this grabs data from my database
 Reader.conduits = reader;
```

The problem I have is when `Invalidate()` is called, without re-assigning the Reader class variable its data, it's variables are emptied, even tho' they have recently been populated, and displayed on the screen.
At first, I thought I was having the common "paint event object disappearing" but it's definetly that my class variables keep disposing when this shouldn't happen on static variables.

Are there any common reasons for this?

I know I can re-assign the class variables from the database every time `Invalidate()` is called, but I do a lot of post processing to the data and this would seem very expensive and I want to avoid it.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. The short answer is that `it's variables are emptied` is unlikely - something else must have assigned to it. The easiest way to diagnose these kinds of issues is to change the static fields to be static properties with a backing field. Then put a breakpoint inside the setter to see where / when it is being set.

Comment: Can you post the code that populates `Reader.conduits`? Does it use the `reader` itself, in addition to assigning it to `Reader.conduits`? Could be that you have simply cursored through it to the end-- doing so will affect both `reader` and `Reader.conduits`, since they are just references to the same object.

Comment: note: a data-reader is strictly a "read once" thing; storing them in a static field *makes exactly no sense*; what are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: @Marc Gravell - That is the answer. If you post it as an answer I can accept.
If I add some int variables to my class to capture the last reader line they persist that everything works fine. The data-reader variables however dissapear.
To answer your question, there's a lot of code to decide what to grab from the database, so I didn't want to throw the answer away knowing I need it multiple times to paint objects tot he screen.
What I can do instead is remember the sqlString and call the answer everytime I need to paint therefore only using the reader once.

Comment: Can some please advise why my question has a (-2). It's not a repeat, it's a valid question, it has an answer and I provided the correct amount of code for someone to spot my mistake?

Comment: Are you accessing the DB in the `Invalidate` event? Oh, no! How could you think of such a thing? Why update your data if it hasn't changed? After all, even if the user does not work with your application, and just drag another window on top of yours (this will cause repainting), the database will fly a lot of requests. What for?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov. Yes I am. Sounds like I shouldn't. I'll wear a cone of shame. The reason this is working is that the database changes with almost every click (user adds or deletes nodes and conduits) so I need to repaint.
Agreed, that any other repaint events are wasteful, this is why I wanted to save the reader in a class which caused the origional issue. I suspect the only saving grace is that it is a memory database so accessing data is as cheap as it can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, a data reader (`IDataReader` or `DbDateReader`) can only be consumed once - it is the raw API over an ADO.NET provider. As such, it makes *very* little sense to store a reader in a field (*especially* a static field), as you can't inspect it later (and since it is tied to a connection, it is likely that the connection will have been closed when you try).

Your best bet would be to read the data *into a list*, and store a `List<Foo>` (for some `Foo`) in a field. Tools like "dapper" can make that simple, so you don't need to write any code to deal with the reader, for example:

```
int id = ...
someField = connection.Query<Order>(
    "select top 5 * from Orders where CustomerId = @id",
    new { id }).AsList();
```